# Compare two similar directories and list differences between files

Tags: diff, file-comparison, file-management

Suppose I have same version of linux kernel but I changed some driver lines. Is there any way to compare these kernels and list the results. The result would be helpful to go back if I changed a lot in original drivers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The traditional method:

```
diff -r dir1  dir2
```

That gives you a file-by-file difference, which can be kind of wordy. If you have Gnu `diff`,
you can try:

```
diff -r --brief dir1 dir2
```